# Proof that the single variable fragment of first order logic is equivalent to an S5-like modal logic

Tags: modal-logic

I think I read that a single sorted logic is a logic in which there is only one unique variable symbol permitted. In other words, there is only one “parameter of variation” amongst all sentences of the logic.

It is said that the “theory” generated by a logic is the collection of all tautologies. I suppose this means that for any sentence S in this logic, if it contains some sub-expression *E* depending on variable *x*, the truth of sentence S will not depend on if that subexpression *E(x)* is true or false. Perhaps a better way to observe the dynamics of the logic could be to list the truth value of all predicates depending on the value of variable *x*, for example, *P(x)* is true when x = element 1 (in the domain of discourse), and false when x = element 2.

This means that a single-sorted logic is not a logic which only has one *referent* (ie, it is not the case that the logic describes properties of one single thing); but instead, that it can only talk about one thing at a time. If you had 2 unique variable symbols both ranging over the same domain of discourse, then you could express relationships between two things, eg, enemy(dog) = cat, or something.

What is the intuitive significance of a single sorted logic? I can give two examples of when a particular conceptualization made me understand an idea in logic better. One was the idea of “negative infallibility”. The other was one of the axioms of modal logics, **K**, the distribution axiom. I can provide examples of how their symbolic form seemed quizzical to me until I saw an intuitive example of where they came from.

I read that single sorted logic is proven isomorphic to I think weak normal modal logic (also denoted **K**). What is the proof of this?

---

Edit:

I got the details wrong because I was trying to gather some disparate thoughts off the cuff. This is what I was referring to:

[One-variable fragments of first-order logics](https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.15806)

> The one-variable fragment of a first-order logic may be viewed as an "S5-like" modal logic, where the universal and existential quantifiers are replaced by box and diamond modalities, respectively.

Comment: Do you have any info on single sorted logic?

Comment: Single sorted logic seems to just be first order logic, unless I understood you wrong. Idk in what sense first order logic is isomorphic to modal logic. Their expressive power aren’t the same; there are structures that are equivalent under modal logic but not first order equivalent

Comment: Your use of term "single sorted logic" is not standard. A single sorted logic is just that: a logic with only one *sort* of variable, *not* one unique variable. Contrast with a multi-sorted logic, which essentially allows us to partition our domain into types. For a very gentle introduction, see Mitchell FPL ch3 (they use the language of algebras, but the ideas are the same).  As for your purported proof, you will need to state the actual theorem and terms with more clarity I think

Comment: They're not equivalent as K has more restrictions intuitively. Single sorted logics are quantified and in your mentioned modal logic K there's no quantifier, thus to make possible embedding of K into single sorted logic, say FOL as one of its sound & complete fragments, intuitively you just need to sort its possible worlds as a domain based on its Kripke semantics and further introduce accessible relation to express the 2 modalities. Of course K also has a topological semantics (see modal logic wikipedia), you need more advanced algebra with interior operator framework to achieve embedding...

Comment: I messed up the details and restated the question. @DoubleKnot Could you expand on that in an answer? Would love to know more.